# How to stop VBA function showing formula result in Arguments Dialog in MS Excel

Tags: excel, vba

When we add a UDF to MS-Excel using VBA, the function gets evaluated twice when inserting:

1) As soon as all the arguments are given to the function in FUNCTION ARGUMENTS dialog: Hence the result is shown in FUNCTION ARGUMENTS dialog itself as Formula Result

2) After clicking OK in FUNCTION ARGUMENTS dialog: Hence the result is shown in the respective cell.

I also referred to [Stop VBA Evaluate from calling target function twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611929/stop-vba-evaluate-from-calling-target-function-twice) but it made the function does not get evaluated ever.

Can I please know a way of stopping this double evaluation of a UDF function?

Thanks

Comment: you may want to post the function ( edit your original post ) because its hard to analyse something you cannot see...

Comment: How about `Function dummyFunction(dummy As Integer)
Debug.Print "Result:" & dummy
End Function` and you will see that it gets evaluated a few times, as per the question above

Answer (score 2):

If the problem of the double evaluation is speed considerations (the UDF takes a long time to calculate) then I suggest the following.

1. adding an extra parameter called `doCalculate` to the UDF
2. put FALSE in cell A1 in the worksheet
3. point the UDF `doCalculate` parameter to cell A1
4. add a line of code to exit the function if `doCalculate` is false

This way the UDF will not calculate from the Function Dialog. However you could activate the UDF by changing A1 to TRUE