# Excel VBA own function in worksheet which changes value on a sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm trying to use my own VBA function in an Excel sheet with a return value and the same function manipulates a cell on the same or on an other sheet, but the result is `#VALUE!` A minimal working example (Office Prof Plus 2010, 32-bit):

```
Function abc() As Integer
   Dim i%
   i = 0
   Sheet1.Cells(1, 2).Value = 2
   abc = i
End Function
```

When I execute `Debug.Print abc` it obviously writes a `2` to the cell `B2` and the printed result is `0`. What I want to do now is `=abc()` in cell `A1` on `Sheet1`, but I only get `#VALUE!`. Btw, it doesn't work either if `Application.EnableEvents` and `Application.Calculation` is disabled resp. set to manual.

Two questions: Why? And any idea how to resolve? Thx.

Comment: [See this Q for a workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23433096/445425)

Comment: Note that in the workaround, there is a problem (bug?) that the `Evaluate` is run twice.  [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2611929/445425) for a workaround to _that_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's well known that you can't update the worksheet with a UDF (other than the cell with the UDF in). However, there is a pretty awful workaround which checks every time you make a change on your worksheet and places a `2` in `B1` for you if your function happens to be `=abc()`

Have your dummy function in in a standard module

```
Public Function abc() As Integer
    abc = 0
End Function
```

Then in the Sheet1 module place the following code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Target.Formula = "=abc()" Then
        Me.Cells(1, 2).Value = 2
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of User Defined Function *(called from within a cell)* can't modify cell values other than to return a value to the cell containing the UDF.