# Why does Excel/VBA UDF call a sub twice when the Evaluate function is used?

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to have my udf insert a matrix at an offset to the cell where the udf is used.  Im using a 'trick' i've seen documented here: https://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/how-to-change-another-cell-with-a-vba-function-udf/

However it crashes each time i try to do this with an array. In debugging the issue, i've come to learn that the evaluated function was being called multiple times.   I then set ```Application.EnableEvents = False".  After doing this, i still see the evaluated function being called twice.  Why is this?

```
Public Function Test()
    Dim evalstr As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Debug.Print "test 1"
    evalstr = "TestProxy(" & ActiveCell.Address(False, False) & ")"
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Evaluate evalstr
    Debug.Print "test 2"
ExitFunction:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Function
    
ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    Resume ExitFunction
End Function

Private Sub TestProxy(rng As Range)
    Dim arr(1, 1) As Variant, evalstr As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Debug.Print "proxy 1"
    arr(0, 0) = 100
    arr(0, 1) = 101
    arr(1, 0) = 101
    arr(1, 1) = 101
    'rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(2, 2).value = arr
    Debug.Print "proxy 2"

ExitSub:
    Exit Sub
    
ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    Resume ExitSub
End Sub
```

And the output in the Immediate window shows that evaluated Sub, TestProxy, being called twice:

```
test 1
proxy 1
proxy 2
proxy 1
proxy 2
test 2
```

Anyone know why this may be?
Also, anyone know why when i uncomment the commented-out line in the above code, it works the first time, then crashes on subsequent re-evaluation of the cell?

Thanks

Comment: Without input parameter it runs only once. "TestProxy()"

Comment: Previously documented: https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/evaluate-functions-and-formulas-fun-how-to-make-excels-evaluate-method-twice-as-fast/#:~:text=I%20am%20fairly%20sure%20that%20there%20is%20a%20bug%20in%20Application.Evaluate%20that%20actually%20does%20the%20evaluation%20twice.

Answer (score 2):

You could at least short-circuit inside `TestProxy` to exit when the method is called twice with the same address:

```vb
Public Function Test()
    
    Dim evalstr As String, c As Range, addr As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set c = Application.ThisCell 'where the formula is
    addr = c.Address(False, False)
    Debug.Print "Test called from " & addr & " on " & c.Parent.Name
    evalstr = "TestProxy(" & addr & ")"
    c.Parent.Evaluate evalstr '### use Worksheet.Evaluate method not Application
    Exit Function
    
ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
End Function

Private Sub TestProxy(rng As Range)
    Static addr As String               'to store address of last call
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    If rng.Address = addr Then Exit Sub 'second call?
    Debug.Print "TestProxy for " & rng.Address
    rng.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value = Array("A", "B") 'do something
    addr = rng.Address                  'save this cell address
ExitSub:
    Exit Sub
    
ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    Resume ExitSub
End Sub
```

Note also explicit use of the `Worksheet.Evaluate` method (not the default `Application.Evaluate`, which runs in the context of whatever happens to be the activesheet when your formula get called...)

Answer (score 1):

If you add a `Debug.Print Application.Caller.Address` at the beginning of `TestProxy` you will see that the first call always refers to `A1` and the second call to your active cell. I don't have an explanation for that.

What you can do is to add a check like this:

```vb
    If Application.Caller.Address(False, False) = rng.Address(False, False) Then
        Debug.Print "proxy 1"
        arr(0, 0) = 100
        arr(0, 1) = 101
        arr(1, 0) = 101
        arr(1, 1) = 101
        rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(2, 2).Value = arr
        Debug.Print "proxy 2"
    End If
```

But it still fails when you call the UDF from `A1`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to:

```
Public Function Test()
    Dim evalstr As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Debug.Print "test 1"
    evalstr = "0+TestProxy(" & ActiveCell.Address(False, False) & ")"
    ActiveSheet.Evaluate evalstr
    Debug.Print "test 2"
ExitFunction:
    Exit Function    
    ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    Resume ExitFunction
End Function
```

For more PS: [Stop VBA Evaluate from calling target function twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611929/stop-vba-evaluate-from-calling-target-function-twice)

Comment: For me it also runs two times. In addition if TestProxy returns a string evalstr will be Error 2015.