# Application.OnTime not works if called with Evaluate function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function, delayed-execution

The target is to reset public variables after calling one or more of the several functions from a sheet. If the process flows in a normal way resetting could be after finishing every functions which detection is not a simply way. Neither if there is any error occurs during run-time. So the idea was wait a short time and reset public variables, indifferentely of the results of the calling. Till now the only way i found, to create a button in a Userform and manually reset the variables which is not an ideal solution.

This issue seems a very simple one, but can't get to an acceptable workaround.

The attempt was to call nmn() as Function, it doesn't run the OnTime (no errors).

These are the Subs in a Standard Module which show the weird execution of the OnTime method.

```
Public val_called(1 to 7) as Integer, flags(1 to 7) as Integer

Sub reset_all()
Debug.Print Now, "reset"
For i = 1 To UBound(val_called)
  val_called(i) = 0
  flags(i) = True
Next i
End Sub

Sub nmn()
'Set my = New Class1
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("0:0:2"), "reset_all"
Debug.Print "we evaluate"
'my.reset_allcall
End Sub

Sub m1()
'Set my = New Class1
Evaluate ("filename.xlsm!nmn()")
'nmn
End Sub
```

The issue is the following:

1. If start nmn() sub then the OnTime works and the printout

```
we evaluate
2024.02.18. 14:49:01        reset
```

2.If start from m1() sub the OnTime doesn't work and seems it is (nmn() sub) called two times immediately (there is no delay between the print of the 2 lines). The printout

```
we evaluate
we evaluate
```

**SIDENOTE** in other posts i found that evaluate is called with only the name of the sub like this: `Evaluate "nmn()"` which not results anything without error. It requires the name of the workbook like `Evaluate "filename.ext!nmn()"`

Disregarding the original target it is **annoying that after a simple call why not executed** the OnTime sub, and why the called Sub **run two times.**

I tried to place the two Subs into different modules, with no avail.

What did i miss, or how can solve to get OnTime to work if  it is called by Evaluate?

This workaround is because the function will be a custom excel function called from a sheet, and the direct invoke of the OnTime method not avail. I tried create a Class also and invoke it but same result.

Comment: See here for the double run observation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611929/stop-vba-evaluate-from-calling-target-function-twice

Comment: @Tim Thanks, i saw it i only mentioned it because that post is 14 years old and i would like to know if there is update or modification in newer versions of Excel for this side effect. For me behaviour like this (adding an add operation for a name) is a quite surprise.

Comment: I don't think there has been any fix but the linked post has a workaround (use the `Worksheet.Evaluate` method, and not the default `Application.Evaluate`)